# Facebook Graph API call without any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

Is it possible to use just Rails (without any gem) to interact with Facebook's Graph API?

Can you provide an example on how to do that and get only the JSON respond back? (with or without access_token)

I think I have to use Net::HTTP or something similar to curl in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by 'interact with'. To simply retrieve a Facebook Graph URL, you can use:

```
  require 'open-uri'
  file = open("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552")
  file.read
```

To parse the JSON,

```
  require 'json'
  JSON.parse()
```

There are a few different HTTP libraries though, and a few different JSON ones - so look around before settling on a solution. Or use one of the gems that abstract away some of the Facebook Graph API calls.

Comment: Thanks mate. I want to do it from scratch. What you suggest is what I was thinking about. Can I also add the access token as a parameter? file = open("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?access_token=....) ?

Comment: Yup. You may need to run URI.parse() on the URL first. eg see http://code.google.com/p/openhandle/wiki/OpenHandleCodeRuby